# Why SpringBoot framework deduce application main class by throw RuntimeException?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Under normal circumstances, when the application starts, the run method of SpringApplication is called in the main method, and the Class object where the main method is located has been passed as a parameter.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(BootApplication.class, args);
}
```

But recently when I was studying the SpringBoot startup process, I saw that the last step of SpringApplication instantiation was to obtain the Class instance of the application's main startup class in the following way

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public SpringApplication(ResourceLoader resourceLoader, Class<?>... primarySources) {
        this.resourceLoader = resourceLoader;
        Assert.notNull(primarySources, "PrimarySources must not be null");
        this.primarySources = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(primarySources));
        this.webApplicationType = WebApplicationType.deduceFromClasspath();
        setInitializers((Collection) getSpringFactoriesInstances(ApplicationContextInitializer.class));
        setListeners((Collection) getSpringFactoriesInstances(ApplicationListener.class));
        // deduce main Class
        this.mainApplicationClass = deduceMainApplicationClass();
    }
```

Why can't Spring directly obtain the main startup class by a method similar to the following judgment What about Class object instances?

```
if (primarySources.size == 1) {
    this.mainApplicationClass = primarySources.get(0);
}else {
    this.mainApplicationClass = deduceMainApplicationClass();
}
```

Comment: What would be the benefit of your way? The advantage of always calling deduceMainApplicationClass() is it works always the same

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my way, there is no need to throw exception stack information and circular comparison when the Application main Class has been passed. Shouldn't it be faster to use the Class reference of this parameter directly?

Comment: This doesn't matter if you look at what Spring Boot does when starting.

Comment: I am making a web framework in java for college and I am also wondering why they are doing it like this. Did you already find an answer to the question we are sharing? Greetings